# adding opencv to cmake --help-module

Tags: opencv, cmake

I like the help which is provided by --help-module. Here you can read how to add new libraries and which variables are being set. Because I only occasionally create a framework from scratch I only add libraries once and forget how to add them for the next time.

So, if I want to create a new project I only have to make a quick search with --help-module and the package I want to use. Unfortunately OpenCV is not in this list. So, I am curious if there is a way to add a help for Opencv?

*TLTR;* I want to add a help for OpenCV. Where I can refresh my mind on how to find opencv and how link against it etc.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this can be done.

The help module is generated from the RST CMake documentation. You are not supposed to add it there. It should be part of the documentation from the project which provides the module.